# PDO Can't bind two attributes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to bind a search term and a limit value to a PDO execute query, but I get error messages no matter which way I do it

```
    public static function searchUsersByName($searchTerm, $results = null) {
    //getDBConnection

    if($results == null) {
        $results = 5;
    }

    $searchTerm = '%'.$searchTerm.'%';

    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_firstname, user_lastname
                                 FROM users_details
                                 WHERE user_firstname LIKE :searchTerm 
                                    OR user_lastname LIKE :searchTerm
                                   LIMIT :results");
    $query->bindParam(':searchTerm', $searchTerm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':results', $results, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();

    $search_results = array();

    foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $user) {
        $search_results[$user->user_id] = new stdClass();
        $search_results[$user->user_id]->user_id = $user->user_id;
        $search_results[$user->user_id]->user_firstname = $user->user_firstname;
        $search_results[$user->user_id]->user_lastname = $user->user_lastname;
    }

    return $search_results;
}
```

This is the error I get from this:

`PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "5"`

It works fine if I take out the bind for LIMIT and just hardcode `5` into the SQL query, but I want to be able to change it if possible

`$query->execute(array(':searchTerm' => '%'.$searchTerm.'%', ':results' => $results));`

I've tried doing it this way, but of course PDO automatically puts quotes around the values its inserting via this method, and as far as I know you can't put a `PDO::PARAM_INT` in while using this method.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that $results is not an integer? The error seems like your PHP code is posting a string into the query, which would explain the error.

I am guessing this is the issue because of the following piece of code

```
if($results == null) {
    $results = 5;
}
```

How is $results set in the first place? Via GET/POST? Then it might have been converted to a string.

I've tried your piece of code myself and casting it to an int fixed it for me.

```
$query->bindParam(':results', intval($results), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the problem! I forgot that $_GET casts an int to a string, the `if($results == null) {$results = 5;}`  made me think it was an int which is why I was confused!